# How to use inputdlg in meshgrid

Tags: matlab

This is an example of the surface mesh plot syntax: I want the variables inside the `meshgrid` to be done using `inputdlg` and the equation in the `z` variable.

```matlab
[x,y] = meshgrid(-2:0.1:2);
z = x.*exp(-((x-y.^2).^2 + y.^2)); 
mesh(x,y,z)
```

Comment: In what way does the documentation "not help"? What have you tried? Are you getting specific errors?

Comment: Hi, I am not familiar with how matlab syntax works and variable passing but what I want to do with the given code is to replace the values inside the meshgrid and the z variable expression  to be becoming from an  inputdlg command rather than being pre-defined. The documentation from their website does not show such scenario.

Comment: How important is the plotting density `0.1` for you? Is using a function plot sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that might be interesting is to use anonymous functions. A function can be parsed from a string using the function `str2func()`. The character arrays within the dialogue boxes can be parsed to integers using `str2double()`. Depending on how important it is to have the data points for the Z-function and to be able to set the plotting density/interval this may be an option to opt-in for.

**Summary:**

• Use anonymous functions → independent variables defined within `@()`.

• Grab input variables from dialogue boxes.

• Plot on the specified domain using `fmesh()`.

[image: Input Dialog and Output Plot Results]

```
%Setting the prompts/field names%
Prompts = {'Axis Minimum','Axis Maximum','Function Equation'};

%Setting the dialog modal title%
Dialog_Title = 'Dialog Title: Change Me';

%Setting the dimensions of each input field%
Field_Dimensions = [1 50];

%Default Inputs/Placeholders%
Default_Inputs = {'-2','2','@(x,y)x.*exp(-((x-y.^2).^2 + y.^2))'};

%Grabbing the answers from the input dialog%
Answers = inputdlg(Prompts,Dialog_Title,Field_Dimensions,Default_Inputs);

%Grabbing the answers from the "Answers" array%
Axis_Minimum = str2double(Answers{1});
Axis_Maximum = str2double(Answers{2});
Z_Function = str2func(Answers{3});

%Plotting the function given the axis boundaries%
fmesh(Z_Function,[Axis_Minimum Axis_Maximum Axis_Minimum Axis_Maximum]);
```

**Using MATLAB version: R2019b**